# RPN outputting incorrect data: C

Tags: c, pointers, stack, rpn

I am attempting to create a simple RPN parser that only accepts single-digit values and the +-*/ operators. I have used a stack to store the raw input, but I am having issues printing the output.

When I run the debug, it gives the error message "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.", tied to line 94. the Input I used in this case was 11+. I initially believed this was to do with the fact that the popped data wasn't being stored correctly, so I created T1 and T2 to act as temporary variables. However this does not fix the issue. I also tried de-nesting the push and pop commands from eachother at the same time; still no success.

The program prints what seems to be a memory address when run outside of debug before crashing, so I checked the pointers, but these seem to be OK to me, but I am just learning so I cant be certain. Thanks in advance!

the lib.c file is here:

```
#include "defs.h"
//Initialising the stack
TopStack *initTOS()
{
TopStack *pTopStack;
pTopStack=(TopStack*)malloc(sizeof(TopStack));
return(pTopStack);
}

//Pushing an element onto the stack
void push( TopStack *ts, int val)
{
if(ts->num==0)
{
    Stack *pNewNode;
    pNewNode=(Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    pNewNode->val=val;
    pNewNode->next=NULL;
    ts->top=pNewNode;
    ts->num++;
}
else if(ts->num!=0)
{
    Stack *pNewNode;
    pNewNode=(Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    pNewNode->val=val;
    pNewNode->next=ts->top;
    ts->top=pNewNode;
    ts->num++;
}
}

int pop(TopStack *ts)
{
if(ts->num==0)
    {
        printf("Can't pop, stack is empty!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
else{
        Stack *pTemp = ts->top;
        int RemovedValue;
        RemovedValue=pTemp->val;
        ts->top=pTemp->next;
        ts->num--;
        free(pTemp);
        return (RemovedValue);
    }
}

void testStack(TopStack *ts)
{
int RemovedValue;
push(ts,1);
push(ts,2);
printf("the popped value was %i\n",pop(ts));
printf("the popped value was %i\n",pop(ts));
}

void parseRPN(TopStack *st)
{
char Input[50];
int i;
do{
    printf("please enter an expression in single-digit integers using RPN:\n");
    scanf("%49s",&Input);
    if (strlen(Input)>=50)
        {
            printf("that expression was too large for the RPN engine to handle! please break it down into smaller sub-tasks.\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            continue;
        }
    break;
}while(true);

for (i=0; Input[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        if ((isdigit(Input[i])==0) && ((Input[i] != '+') && (Input[i] != '-') && (Input[i] != '*') && (Input[i] != '/')))
        {
            printf("Error: Invalid operand to RPN\nExiting...\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else printf("accepted %c for processing...\n",Input[i]);
    }
for (i=0; Input[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
     if (isdigit(Input[i]==0))
     {
         push(st,Input[i]);
         break;
     }
     else if (Input[i] != '+')
     {
         int T1=pop(st);
         int T2=pop(st);
         T1=T1+T2;
         push(st,T2);
         break;
     }
     else if (Input[i] != '-')
     {
          push(st,(pop(st)-pop(st)));
          break;
     }
     else if (Input[i] != '*')
     {
         push(st, (pop(st)*pop(st)));
         break;
     }
     else if (Input[i] != '/')
     {
         int Operand2=pop(st);
            if(Operand2==0)
            {
                printf("attempt to divide by 0: answer is Infinite!\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                push(st,pop(st)/Operand2);
                break;
            }
     }
    }
}

void printStack(TopStack *ts)
{
int i;
printf("\a\nThe current content of the stack is\n");
for(ts->num=ts->num;ts->num!=0;ts->num--)
{
    printf("%i",ts->top->val);
    break;
}
}
```

Here is defs.h (I can't change this as part of the assignment, it was given to me):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_EXPR 50


//struct that contains stack's element

typedef struct stack_elem{
int val;
struct stack_elem *next;
} Stack;

//struct that contains the pointer to the top of the stack

typedef struct{
int num;//num of elements in stack
Stack *top;;//top of stack
} TopStack;

//ts=pointer to the top of stack, val=element to push

void push( TopStack *ts, int val); //push element on the stack

//prints the elements in the stack

void printStack(TopStack *ts);

// initialize the structure that will point to the top of the stack
```

TopStack *initTOS();

```
// a simple test for the stack

void testStack(TopStack *ts);

// ts=pointer to the top of stack

int pop(TopStack *ts);//returns element from top of stack
//  simple parser function for RPN expressions that assumes numbers have only one digit

void parseRPN(TopStack *st);

// empties the stack using the pop operation

void emptyStack(TopStack *ts);

// performs the operation defined by character op on the elements on top of stack

void performOp(TopStack *st, char op);
```

and here is main.c:

```
#include "defs.h"

int main()
{
TopStack *tp;

tp=initTOS();// initialize the top of stack structure
// testStack(tp);// this function tests your stack
parseRPN(tp);
printStack(tp);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: First problem: in the `initTOS()` function, after allocating `TopStack *pTopStack;`, it is necessary to initialize both `int num` and `Stack *top`. Add `pTopStack->num = 0;` and `pTopStack->top = NULL;`. **WARNING:** in the `printStack()` function, the for-loop is so incredible `for(ts->num=ts->num;ts->num!=0;ts->num--)` !!!!

Comment: I never had problems initialising the stack when I tested it using the testStack function, but I have added it in for safety's sake. Any suggestions on the impossible `for()` loop? I think this is where the issue is...

Comment: When testing you source code with `'11+'`, I obtain **"Can't pop, stack is empty!"** because I assume in RPN, before adding a number it is necessary to add one number in the stack.

Comment: Except if `'11+'` has to be parsed as `'1'`, `'1'` and `'+'`.

Comment: 11+ should be parsed as I) integer is 1, push to stack. II) integer is 1, push to stack. III) '+' character. pop 2 elements from stack, sum them, and then push them back again.

Comment: thats interesting that you get something different from me, it may be worth note that I am using the GNU GCC compiler included in CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where looking in your source code, I have detected the following errors:

> **Error 1:** In `parseRPN()`, a series of errors in the if-condition `isdigit()`.

```
if (isdigit(Input[i])!=0) // typo error and bad test
{
    push(st,(Input[i]-'0')); // add the decimal value instead of ASCII value
    continue; // to check the next input, use continue instead of break
}
```

Instead of

```
if (isdigit(Input[i]==0))
{
    printf("push(%c),",Input[i]);
    push(st,(Input[i]-'0'));
    break;
}
```

> **Error 2:** In `parseRPN()`, a series of errors in the "+"operator.

```
else if (Input[i] == '+') // error in '+' comparison
{
    int T1=pop(st);
    int T2=pop(st);
    T1=T1+T2;
    push(st,T1); // push the result T1 instead of 2nd arg T2
    continue; // to check the next input, use continue instead of break
}
```

Instead of

```
 else if (Input[i] != '+')
 {
     int T1=pop(st);
     int T2=pop(st);
     T1=T1+T2;
     push(st,T2);
     break;
 }
```

> **Error 3:** In `parseRPN()`, a series of errors in the "-"operator.

```
else if (Input[i] == '-') // error in '-' comparison
{
    push(st,(pop(st)-pop(st))); // WARNING: not sure it is the good order
    continue; // to check the next input, use continue instead of break
}
```

> **Error 4:** In `parseRPN()`, a series of errors in the "*"operator.

```
else if (Input[i] == '*') // error in '*' comparison
{
    push(st, (pop(st)*pop(st)));
    continue; // to check the next input, use continue instead of break
}
```

> **Error 5:** In `parseRPN()`, a series of errors in the "/"operator.

```
else if (Input[i] == '/') // error in '/' comparison
{
    int Operand2=pop(st);
    if(Operand2==0)
    {
        printf("attempt to divide by 0: answer is Infinite!\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        push(st,pop(st)/Operand2);
        continue; // to check the next input, use continue instead of break
    }
}
```

> **Error 6:** In `printStack()`, replacing for-loop by a while to display all values in the stack.

```
Stack *pTemp;

pTemp = ts->top; // start of stack
while (pTemp!=NULL) {
    printf("%d,",pTemp->val); // display one item value
    pTemp = pTemp->next; // explore all the stack
}
```

Instead of

```
for(ts->num=ts->num;ts->num!=0;ts->num--)
{
    printf("%i",ts->top->val);
    break;
}
```

Comment: This solves the error I initilly encountered, but there was a bit of tidying up to do as it also printed a lot of garbage after the real result. Thanks! :)